# First WordPress ACF First Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to follow the following instructions to create my first ACF block.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/

I created a directory in the plugins directory called 'testimonial' then added a file 'testimonial.php' which contains the following:

```js
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks' );
function register_acf_blocks() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/testimonial' );
}
```

I changed the plugin directory to '/testimonial'

I also added a block.json file:

```js
{
    "name": "acf/testimonial",
    "title": "Testimonial",
    "description": "A custom testimonial block.",
    "style": ["file:./testimonial.css"],
    "category": "formatting",
    "icon": "admin-comments",
    "keywords": ["testimonial", "quote"],
    "acf": {
        "mode": "preview",
        "renderTemplate": "testimonial-template.php"
    },
    "align": "full"
}
```

Plus two empty files 'testimonial-template.php' and 'testimonial.css'.

If I display the list of plugins in WordPress my plugin isn't listed. I was expecting to see it listed as 'testimonial'.

I'm running Wordpress 6.0.2 and have ACF Pro installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've added the necessary files to make a plugin. Try following https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/

You can, of course, add that code you listed into functions.php (or a file that is loaded by functipns.php) to do your testing outside the environment of a plugin.

Comment: Hi Tony,

Thank you for your reply.

I've looked at the documentation you mention, I can see that it says at a minimum, a header comment must contain the Plugin Name, I don't know if that's what you were alluding to.

Isn't the definition for the plugin defined in block.json?

I'm trying to create the plugin according to the ACF documentation here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/
The PHP does not contain a plugin name.

Steve

Comment: I put the following at the top of the testimonical.php file:
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Testimonial
 * Plugin URI:        https://example.com/plugins/the-basics/
 * Description:       A testimonical plugin
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Author:            Steve
 * Author URI:        https://netmonics.com/
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 * Text Domain:       testimonial
 */

I can now activate the plugin.

Though now I get the contents of the block.json file displayed at the top of the WordPress admin UI.

Comment: I forgot to put <?php before the header, the block.json no longer displays in the Wordpress admin UI.

Comment: Steve,  WordPress Plugins and Gutenberg Blocks are 2 completely different beasts. You can register a Block within a Plugin.  You don't have to.
The block.json file defines the characteristics of the Block you are registering.  Now't to do with the Plugin that the code sits in.

Comment: Is working now, or at least it's displaying some text on a page.

Comment: Tony, 

OK thanks.

I just want my blocks to be plugins so I can use them independently of the theme. 

I've understood that plugins and blocks are not the same, never tried creating a block outside of a plugin so not sure of the difference.